# What effects do the APP_ENV and APP_DEBUG constants have in a Symfony application?

Tags: php, symfony

What do the various settings for these environment variables do?

My current guess is that `APP_ENV` is used only for choosing which config to load (`config/packages/{APP_ENV}/*`) and `APP_DEBUG` turns on/off additional console output for kernel events, and enables debugging views for exceptions etc.

Is this correct or do these variables do additional things?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### `APP_ENV` Uses:

#### Decide which configuration files to load in the configuration directory.

This is accomplished in within your `Kernel` class.

By default, in the  `configureContainer()` method provided you'll find this line, where `$this->environment` represents the value of `APP_ENV`.

```php
$loader->load( $confDir . '/{packages}/' . $this->environment . '/**/*' . self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob' );
```

Obviously, you could customize and or change that behaviour according your your needs.

#### Decide which `.env` files to load.

In the file `config/bootstrap.php` you'll see the basic environment initialization.  This script uses the `DotEnv` component to read the `.env` files

```php
(new Dotenv())->loadEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
```

And this component will use the value of `APP_ENV` to search for these. If you take a look at `DotEnv::loadEnv()` you will see this:

```php
if (file_exists($p = "$path.$env")) {
    $this->load($p);
}

if (file_exists($p = "$path.$env.local")) {
    $this->load($p);
}
```

Which means that for a given `APP_ENV` set as `dev` it will try to load first `.env.dev` and then `.env.dev.local`.

#### To set the value of `APP_DEBUG`, if it's not explicitly set.

If you do not set `APP_DEBUG`, it will be set by `bootstrap.php` according to the value of `APP_ENV`. This can be seen clearly here on this line:

```php
$_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] = $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? $_ENV['APP_DEBUG'] ?? 'prod' !== $_SERVER['APP_ENV'];
```

(If `$_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']` is available use that, if not try to use `$_ENV['APP_DEBUG']`, and if that is not set either set it `true` if `APP_ENV` is not `prod`).

### `APP_DEBUG` Uses:

This constant is used on entry points scripts for the application (`public/index.php` or `bin/console`), where you would see these two uses:

#### To initialize error reporting and error handling globally. This is done using `Debug::enable()`:

```php
if ( $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ) {
    umask( 0000 );

    Debug::enable();
}
```

The method `Debug::enable()` is simple and easy to understand: It changes `error_reporting`, sets `displays_errors`, and registers error and exception handlers.

#### To initialize `Kernel` for the application.

```php
$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
```

This sets the `%kernel.debug%` (`Kernel::isDebug()`) parameter. This can value can be used by many packages to make decisions about what to do when the system is deemed to be in debugging mode. There is no mandated behaviour, each module can use the information in the most suitable manner for the module use-case.

Comment: I use those constants to control the amount of logging produced by the application and access to some dev only API paths.

Comment: Note that the auto computing of the `APP_DEBUG` flag is now done in `DotEnv::bootEnv` in the `index.php` file.