# How and where is $_SERVER[ 'APP_DEBUG' ] set in Symfony >=5.1?

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, symfony5

On line 12 of the `index.php` script file that Symfony version 5 created when I ran the `symfony new <project> --full` command, shown below, there is an if-test that when the **$_SERVER[ 'APP_DEBUG' ]** super global is `true`, enables Symfony's Debug class.

```
use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

( new Dotenv() )->bootEnv( dirname( __DIR__) . '/.env' );

if( $_SERVER[ 'APP_DEBUG' ] ) {

    umask( 0000 );

    Debug::enable();

} // End of if( $_SERVER[ 'APP_DEBUG' ] ) ...

$kernel = new Kernel( $_SERVER[ 'APP_ENV' ],
                     (bool)$_SERVER[ 'APP_DEBUG' ] );
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle( $request );
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate( $request, $response );
```

In the controllers called by the above code, I want to use a similar test to determine when my application is running in debug mode, but I want to know is how and where is `$_SERVER[ 'APP_DEBUG' ]` set?

For the question "What effects do the APP_ENV and APP_DEBUG constants have in a Symfony application?" The bootstrap.php can set the $_SERVER[ 'APP_DEBUG' ], but in my case, the bootstrap.php script isn't called and it isn't one of the third-party scripts under vendors.

If it is in **$_SERVER[ 'APP_ENV' ]**, how did it get there?

Note: [What effects do the APP_ENV and APP_DEBUG constants have in a Symfony application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57448843/what-effects-do-the-app-env-and-app-debug-constants-have-in-a-symfony-applicatio) appears to suggest that the **bootstrap.php** script could be setting the debug flag in **$_SERVER[ 'APP_ENV' ]**, but this script isn't part of the installed vendor packages or under the **config** directory, so isn't called, and so can't have set this flag.

Nigel Ren, offered:

Looks like the .env file (stackoverflow.com/questions/54252210/…).

However, my project's `.env` file doesn't have an entry for `APP_DEBUG`.

Is there a default value somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value used to be set on `bootstrap.php`, which came with Symfony <5.1 flex recipes.

Since Symfony 5.1 the file is no longer included on the recipe, and the same is done by the `DotEnv` component directly, on the `bootEnv()` method (which, by default, is called in the front-controller, either `index.php` or `console`).

```
// index.php
(new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__) . '/.env');
```

The doc-block for [that method](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv/blob/783f12027c6b40ab0e93d6136d9f642d1d67cd6b/Dotenv.php#L148) says:

```
/**
 * Loads env vars from .env.local.php if the file exists or from the other .env files otherwise.
 *
 * This method also configures the APP_DEBUG env var according to the current APP_ENV.
 *
 * See method loadEnv() for rules related to .env files.
 */
```

And includes a similar method than what `bootstrap.php` used to include:

```
$k = $this->debugKey;
$debug = $_SERVER[$k] ?? !\in_array($_SERVER[$this->envKey], $this->prodEnvs, true);
$_SERVER[$k] = $_ENV[$k] = (int) $debug || (!\is_bool($debug) && filter_var($debug, \FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) ? '1' : '0';
```

Basically, if you don't set the value explicitly, it will default to `true` to "non-prod" environments, and by default only `prod` is a production environment.